# How to configure Lucene to use a custom codec from external JAR?

Tags: ant, lucene, codec

As part of my studies I need to implement a custom Lucene codec, targetting Lucene 5.3.1.

I've tried following the instructions here:

http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/06/05/build-your-own-lucene-codec/ to get started, but I am having some trouble getting the codec to load when running Lucene tests.

I've uploaded a minimal project at https://github.com/sigbjornlo/codecs

Running **mvn package** generates a jar with a file *`META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec`* containing a single line:

```
edu.ntnu.sigbjornlo.codecs.HelloCodec
```

...which is where the codec class resides at. It's just a FilterCodec subclass that does nothing extra.

Running **ant -Dtestcase=TestSegmentTermDocs -Dtests.codec=HelloCodec -lib /path/to/hello-1.0.jar** test gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'HelloCodec' does not exist.  
You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  
The current classpath supports the following names: [SimpleText, Asserting, CheapBastard, FastCompressingStoredFields, FastDecompressionCompressingStoredFields, HighCompressionCompressingStoredFields, DummyCompressingStoredFields, Lucene53]
```

What might I be doing wrong here? Is there any way to make Lucene's SPI loader log what it's trying and/or failing to load, and why?